# Final Cut Express 3.5 project to Final Cut Express 4

Tags: video-editing, final-cut-express

Can an FCE 3.5 project be opened in FCE 4? And, can you open an FCE 4 project in FCE 3.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, now that I have FCE 4, I can answer this. Yes, you can open an FCE 3.5 project in FCE 4. **But** when you open the FCE 3.5 project, you will be asked to save it in an FCE 4 compatible project. This means that you will be left with two files, an older file that can be opened in FCe 3.5, and a newer one that only can be opened in FCE 4.